# Append Entity on Microsoft Azure Table Storage Insert or Replace

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-table-storage

I want to append something on entity while it exists and do not append the entity if it doesn't exist. How will I be able to achieve it? I tried following but it doesn't work the way I want.

task = table_service.get_entity('datas', '..com','asss','Hello')
table_service.insert_or_replace_entity('tasktable', task)

If the entity exists :
I want to append that hello with something as:
('datas', '..com','asss','Hello;123')

If the entity doesnt exist :
I want to insert as:
('datas', '..com','asss','Hello')

Comment: Please edit your question and include what you're expecting and what's the actual result you're getting. Do provide all the details that you can.

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS can you please look at it again , i am sorry i suck at explaining.

Comment: You need to do better than this . Please take some time and define the problem more clearly. You may want to look at inset_or_merge operation instead of insert_or_replace. HTH.

Comment: According to your need, you need to use `inset_or_merge` method. If the entity exists, it will call merge operation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/merge-entity. If the entity doesn't exist, it will call insert operation ; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/insert-entity

Comment: @JimXu I tried  insert_or_merge as well but it also replaces the existing entity instead of merging/appending it . 

`task006 = {'PartitionKey': '..com', 'RowKey': 'a','description':'hello'}
task = table_service.insert_or_merge_entity('datas',task006)
print(task)`

I did this. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: @DineshTiwari  According to my understanding, the original entity is like `{'PartitionKey': '..com', 'RowKey': 'a','description':'123'}`. Then you update the entity. After that, it should be like`{'PartitionKey': '..com', 'RowKey': 'a','description':'hello;123'}`. Right?

Comment: @DineshTiwari Besides, could you please tell me which sdk you use?

Comment: @JimXu Yes, my goal is exactly like you mentioned above. I am using [azure-cosmos-db-table](https://pypi.org/project/azure-cosmosdb-table/) in python3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to append something to one existing entity property's value, it is impossible. Because Azure table storage does not provide any operation to do that.  Azure Table storage just provides operations to manage entity and it does not provide operations to manage Azure table entity properties. So you just can set a new value for one existing entity property.

Regarding how to do that, we can use `update` or `merge` operation. But please note that the two operations will cause  different result. The `update` operation replaces the entire entity. Those properties from the previous entity will be removed if the request does not define or include them. The `merge` operation does not replace the existing entity. Those properties from the previous entity will be retained if the request does not define or include them.